# Intent flags and launchMode

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I have a service `S` which gets started as soon as the boot is completed. I have an application with one **Activity** which binds to the service `S` when the app is launched.

Now I have registered a broadcast receiver for certain event so that if the event occurs I should launch the same **Activity**. I don't want another instance of the same **Activity** to be created, I want to reuse the **Activity** but `onCreate()` or `onRestart()` method of the **Activity** should be called.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% positive of your question, but here we go.  You could try using a static method in your mainactivity and call it from your service.

In your main activity:

```
  @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    superAwesomeMethod();

public static void superAwesomeMethod() {
    //stuff you want called on onCreate
```

then in your Service:

```
//event listener capture
YourActivityName.superAwesomeMethod();
```

Comment: You should accept this answer if it was helpful to you. Click the green checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try your `AndroidManifest.xml` with this

```
<activity android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

for your main activity

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand intents go for

http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/04/15/android-activites-and-tasks-series-intent-flags/

its very clear and the demo app coming along with it really helpful.